# Jquery/CSS, how to have and access multiple (left) panels, while adjusting main content container automatically

Tags: jquery, css

I've been diving into more advanced CSS and JQuery to build a particular layout, but am stuck on something - I don't know if I'm missing something really obvious, or if this requires more complex scripting to achieve. I've searched for days, and can't seem to find a Jquery and CSS example that is even close enough for me to tweak and adjust. It's easy to find single sliding panel demos, but nothing that accommodates two or three overlapping panels, and which allows also shows how to position main content alongside the moving panels.

I'm trying to get three panels to slide in/out from the left side of the window, using handles that are on the panels themselves (like a vertical version of the handle at the bottom of the text field I'm using to post this question). The panels need to also be smart enough to allow any/all to be opened at the same time (and still leave that 15px piece along the right edge of each panel so users can always click any handle for any panel). Lastly, as any/all panels move in or out, the main content block needs to adjust its width automatically. Bonus if panels can set a cookie to remember their last positions, if I refresh the browser window.

The JQuery would need to know the open/close state of each panel, and the positioning of each panel - which could differ depending on whether any other panels are open or closed before and after the current selected panel. The third panel, for example, could conceivably be in one of four different locations, depending on whether the first and second panels are extended or retracted.

DETAILS:

(A.) The main window holds everything and has all overflow hidden, and height and width are 100% / fluid. (B.) The window has a header bar that will hold some content and controls. Let's say 50px height, and 100% width. (C.) The main content area below right holds content that will scroll (vertically) as needed. (D.) And along the left side, I need the ability to slide in three panels independently in a way that allows users to see any/all of them at once, or retract them when not needed. The panels are 200px wide and 100% vertical, between the header bar and bottom of the window, and when retracted the panels still show about 15px of their right sides, which contain a vertically aligned handle (image) that users can click to make each panel move in or out (depending on the current state). (E.) As each panel opens or closes, the main content space width should adjust automatically.

I've linked to three reference screenshots below, which might explain this better. Any assistance would be appreciated - and Thank You in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm feeling like you should start working on this, and ask questions about specific parts you are having trouble with. It sounds like you have a plan, so why not start coding and ping Stack when you run into a roadblock. You issue could be solved in a myriad of ways. So you will most likely get various responses that may not help. Also, you could use more/less CSS or more/less JS depending on preference/cross-browser support required, etc.

Comment: You're right Leeish - I do prefer questions that are specific and targeted as possible (as you can tell by the lengthy text I wrote in the first place), but in this case I was just stuck with nowhere to start, for this particular problem. I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the above that you should give it a shot on your own, but since I'm in a good mood I got you started with the sliding panels and a VERY brief pop-up from the upper-right hand corner. This is by no means complete, but should give you a good start. Once you get a little further with more specific questions, hit us up again. http://jsfiddle.net/TqNRg/1/. you'll need to play around with `overflow:scroll` in your CSS to get the scrolling right, and the jQuery to show/hide the pop-ups in the upper right.

Edit: Updated the fiddle... forgot to save some changes. This one is closer to complete.

Comment: Thank you Tim! I've lingered around SO for years, but just created an account today. When I get more reputation points I'll be sure to come back and vote up this answer. It's the first solution I've seen to this question.